# Rails 5: iteration with condition to map matching records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method in my `rating/rating.rb` Model, where I basically need to create array of arrays with matching `inventory` and `rating` IDs:

```
def inventory_ratings    
  inventory = Inventory::Inventory.where(id: inv).order(date: :desc)
  rating = Rating::Rating.where(id: rtg).order(valid_from: :desc)

  columns = [:inventory_id, :rating_id]
  values = inventory.map {|inv|
    if (inv.position_id == rating.position_id &&
        rating.valid_from..rating.valid_to.include?(inv.date))
      r = rating.id
    end
    [ inv.id, r ]
  }
  Rating::InventoryRating.import columns, values, validate: false
end
```

At the moment I get this error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method "position_id" for #<Rating::Rating::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffff6067bf8>` since I probably have to somehow iterate through each rating to get `position_id`, `valid_from` and `valid_to`.

**How do I add that extra iteration so each `inventory` record iterates through each rating record and maps if it matches IF statement, please? Thank you!**

Comment: is there any relation between `Inventory` and `Rating`?

Comment: @rony36 Yes, I have this in my `inventory/inventory.rb` model: `has_many :ratings, class_name: 'Rating::Rating', through: :inventory_ratings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
values = []
inventory.each do |inv|
  values.concat([inv.id].product(rating.where('position_id = ? AND valid_from <= ? AND valid_to >= ?', inv.position_id, inv.date, inv.date).ids))
end.uniq.compact
```

Comment: Thank you. I see in console `inventory` is iterating through `ratings`, however at the end I get this error: `ArgumentError: Last argument should be a two dimensional array '[[]]'. First element in array was a Integer`. It looks like I don't get my array of arrays as result.

Comment: sorry, I missed something. I've updated my answer. try it :)

Comment: It seems we're almost there. Now I get array something like this: `[[], [[23, 7]], [[19, 6]], [[18, 6]], [[17, 6]], [[11, 1]]]` How do I make it without those extra [ ], please? I need it to be something like `[ [23,7],[19,6] ]`

Comment: Nevermind, my bad - I had mistake on my side. Your code works like charm :) Thank you!

Comment: great to hear that :)